# How to get unique rows along with the count in sql?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am getting a view like below after I am joining two other tables and the records are unique as well:

**Original**

```
ColA    ColB    ColC    ColD    ColE    ColF
---------------------------------------------
h1      j1      k1      l1      m1      PART
h1      j1      k1      l1      m1      TYPE
```

By using below query:

```
select
  distinct data.ColA,
  ColB,
  ColC,
  ColD,
  data.ColE,
  ColF
from
  data
  join temp.holder x on data.ColA = x.ColA
where
  ColF NOT IN ('ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI')
GROUP BY
  data.ColA,
  ColB,
  ColC,
  ColD,
  data.ColE,
  ColF
ORDER BY
  data.ColA
```

Now I am trying to get unique records from the above view which should give me something like this. Only difference is `ColF` should have count as 2 now since that's the count of unique records.

**Desired Output**

```
ColA    ColB    ColC    ColD    ColE    ColF
--------------------------------------------
h1      j1      k1      l1      m1      2
```

So I tried like this but it gives me duplicate records with lot of data in it. Now sure what I have messed up in my below query?

```
select
  distinct data.ColA,
  ColB,
  ColC,
  ColD,
  data.ColE,
  count(ColF) as ColF
from
  data
  join temp.holder x on data.ColA = x.ColA
where
  ColF NOT IN ('ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI')
GROUP BY
  data.ColA,
  ColB,
  ColC,
  ColD,
  data.ColE,
  ColF
ORDER BY
  data.ColA
```

**Update**

I am seeing data like this:

```
ColA    ColB    ColC    ColD    ColE    ColF
--------------------------------------------
h1      j1      k1      l1      m1      2
h1      j1      k1      l1      m1      1
h1      j1      k1      l1      m1      1
h1      j1      k1      l1      m1      1
h1      j1      k1      l1      m1      2
```

Something is off somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . are you looking for `group by`?

```
select col1, colb, colc, cold, cole, count(*)
from data join
     temp.holder x
     on data.ColA = x.ColA
where ColF NOT IN ('ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI')
group by col1, colb, colc, cold, cole;
```

Comment: Not sure if you fully read my question? I do have same thing in my above question at the end right? Unless I dont need to include `ColF` in my group by clause?

Comment: @AndyP . . . (1) This should do what you want.  (2) I think the difference is that you don't want `colf` in the `group by`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but somehow I do see duplicate values in `cola`, `colb`, `colc`, `cold`, `cole`, but `cole` value is different for each of those `cola-cole` duplicate values?

Comment: @AndyP . . . The five values taken together are unique.   That is what the `group by` does.

Comment: I should get only one row as the output right? But I am not seeing one row in the output for some reason

Comment: @AndyP . . . If you are getting multiple rows that look the same, then perhaps the column *look* the same but have different values -- leading spaces or other hidden characters.

Comment: Problem is `cola-cole` values are same but `colf` count value is different for some reason for each of those rows and thats why I get multiple duplicated rows with your suggestion. Question is why count is different for same `cola-cole` values?

Comment: If cola-col3 have the same values, then there will be one row in the result set with the query in this answer.

Comment: you still around? I am in the chat room. Wanted to confirm on one thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the number of unique `colf` values for the combination of the other columns, you could remove it from your `group by` clause:

```sql
select
  data.ColA,
  ColB,
  ColC,
  ColD,
  data.ColE,
  count(DISTINCT ColF) as ColF
from
  data
  join temp.holder x on data.ColA = x.ColA
where
  ColF NOT IN ('ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI')
GROUP BY
  data.ColA,
  ColB,
  ColC,
  ColD,
  data.ColE
ORDER BY
  data.ColA
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion as ell but somehow I do see duplicate values in `cola`, `colb`, `colc`, `cold`, `cole`, but `cole` value is different for each of those `cola-cole` duplicate values?

Comment: @AndyP I don't understand this comment. Can you please share your data?

Comment: I updated my question with the output I am seeing but if I add distinct in the select clause like this `select distinct data.ColA,` then I get 2 rows only one with colf as 2 and other with 1 as the count. Not sure why

Comment: Btw I don't need to  count number of unique `colf` values. If you compare my original input and my desired output you will see what I need.